# How to have the RemoteView(custom notification) TextView update based on the data in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, notifications

I'm working on a personal project. Now let's say the TextView in the remoteView(that is being run as a foreground notif, not a one-time notification) is updated depending on what data it receives from a firebase connection.

I have included an ondatachanged in the notification method. But even if the data in firebase is updated, the text doesn't seem to change.
What do I need to correct or add in order for the text in the custom notif to change?

Below is the code for the notif method I have:

```
private void runningNotif() {
        RemoteViews viewCollapse = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.activity_notif_collapsed);
        RemoteViews viewExpand = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.activity_notif_expanded);
        String channelID = "CHANNEL_ID_NOTIFICATION";
        Firebase motionValue = new Firebase(*ommitted*);
        motionValue.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class); // Use explicit data type conversion

                if (!value.isEmpty() && !"0".equals(value)) { // Invert the condition to check for non-empty and not equal to "0"
                    System.out.println("Value to lods: " +value);
                    viewExpand.setTextViewText(R.id.rMotionVal,"DETECTED");
                    viewCollapse.setTextViewText(R.id.collapse1,"Cradle");
                } else if ("0".equals(value) || value.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println("Value raw to lods: " +value);
                    viewExpand.setTextViewText(R.id.rMotionVal,"CLEAR");
                    viewCollapse.setTextViewText(R.id.collapse1,"Monitor");
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelID);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notif_logo)
                .setContentTitle("CraMon Dashboard")
                .setCustomContentView(viewCollapse)
                .setCustomBigContentView(viewExpand)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                .putExtra("data", "Some value passed");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel =
                    notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(channelID);
            if (notificationChannel == null) {
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
                notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelID, "Foreground Service", importance);
                notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
                notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            }
        }
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        startForeground(1, notification);
    }
```

This running notif is in a service and below is the code:

```
public class MainActivityService extends Service {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null) {
            runningNotif();
        } else {
            runningNotif();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

It is called to the MainActivity via the code below:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivityService.class);
        startService(serviceIntent);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
//I have ommitted further code as I believe this is only what's needed.
```

Below is the screenshot of the expanded notification.
Note: What's being shown below are the default values.
[image]

PS. I have already implemented the onDataChanged within the MainActivity and it doesn't seem to have problems.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger, so I recommend debugging the app locally and sharing the results here. As step 1: stop ignoring possible error and implement `onCancelled`. At its minimum that should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`. Step 2: If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: The Android docs have a great page on [debugging your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) to get you started with, including the section on [working with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints) and [inspecting varialbles](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#variablesAndWatches).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just posted it here to ask advise from others as I am still a beginner in this to be frank. I'll try to do your advise then.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.